# How to handle JSON with dynamic key in Retrofit?

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit. I am using it for making an API call from my Java app. One of the JSON responses has a dynamic key as mentioned below. I want to catch the response into a POJO.

Here is the response from an API call:

```
{
    key_fixed1: "ABC",
    key_dynamic: { <Fixed Stuff> }
    key_fixed2: "XYZ"
    key_fixed3: "123"
}
```

How to handle the response, especially the dynamic key within a POJO?

Comment: It seems the issue not about retrofit. It's deserializing dynamic json attribute. And Jackson @JsonAnySetter would help you. http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html